# delete command message -Python -discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello I am programming a bot in discord.py, I would like to know if there is a way to delete a message of a command sent by a user for example, the user uses the command .help and the bot deletes the message .help and gives an answer, do you know how to do it?

```py
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.', intents = intents)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def myCmd(message):
  #here the code to clear the message
  await message.send('Something')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def myCmd(ctx):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  await ctx.send('Something')
```

Note that, unless you're deleting your own message, you need `manage_messages` permission to do that.